# how to get list of xmls schemas dependent on given xml schema

Tags: xml, schema

I have a folder having around 300 XML schemas which are inter-dependent. I have a high level schema and I want to know which all child schema files it is dependent on.

Is there any easy way to get this list.

Thanks,
Harish

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a tool like Altova's SchemaAgent would help.

Or write your own depedency analyzer in XSLT. Something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="docs" select="collection('.?select=*.xsd')"/>

<xsl:function name="f:uses" as="document-node()*"/>
  <xsl:param name="schema" as="document-node()"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="for $h in $schema/*/(xs:include/xs:import/xs:redefine)
                        return doc(@href)"/>
</xsl:function>
```

which gives you the files directly used, and then recursive application of this function will give you the files indirectly used.